# Getting Warning while pushing artifacts to Nexus server

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

My Nexus server got server disk space full. By removing some artifacts I could able to login to Nexus UI. But now I have another problem. I can't push artifacts to the Nexus server. When I check nexus logs I can see the below errors.

```
2022-01-19 13:02:11,716+0700 WARN  [qtp1108045838-1612]  admin org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.RetryController - Exceeded retry limit: 8/8 (org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.MissingBlobException: Blob default@2F45BE2F-D98098F1-028E8841-F7C197C4-D7ECA9B9:5441cd8c-1742-4998-8268-85e2330c013f exists in metadata, but is missing from the blobstore)
2022-01-19 13:02:11,716+0700 WARN  [qtp1108045838-1612]  admin 
org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Error: PUT /v2/wso2mi/blobs/uploads/e87a53bb-f2ab-4182-9681-da73f47e12e3
org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.RetryDeniedException: Exceeded retry limit
    at 
org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageTxImpl.allowRetry(StorageTxImpl.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor291.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any way to remove metadata to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

With Nexus 3.16 there is now a task: "Create Repair - Reconcile component database from blob store"

After executing that task, the above issue was fixed. It helps to recreate accidentally deleted blob store still on the disk.